# How to deal with ADHD and OCD like symptoms causing issues during meditation?

Tags: meditation

I am only 2 months into meditating and I've been having some problems.

I am unsure whether I truly have the behavioral/thought patterns that are considered ADHD and/or OCD, but for a while I've been noticing symptoms for a while now.

The problem I am having during meditation is I overthink things to the extreme. I start thinking about whether I am doing it right. Then I overthink so much that I can't even focus on anything else anymore. I have this problem with reading as well. I start thinking about whether Im reading properly and then my mind starts going into overdrive trying to make sure I do every single detail perfectly but instead my brain just fries up and I can't do anything anymore. Then frustration and doubt sets in and it gets even worse.

I know that this is an overall problem that I need to work on and fix. I am working on it. But I would really appreciate any tips on this for now as I feel it is quite a barrier in my process.

EDIT: I came to the realization that I need to remember that those "symptoms" or behavioral patterns are just thoughts accompanied by strong emotions. As with any other thought, acknowledge and let go.

Comment: You might find answers in some of [these previous topics which mention ADHD](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=adhd+is%3Aquestion) (and so this question might be a duplicate)?

Answer (score 1):

If you think you got ADHD or OCD you should seek professional help. Even if it turns out you don't suffer from these disorders talking to an expert could help you with your problem.

Comment: Hello, I'm about to convert this answer to a comment since it does not address the question from the perspective of Buddhist teaching and practice.

Comment: Most professional help is a temporary bandage rather than fixing the root cause. I believe that most mental "disorders" come from past experiences, especially traumatic ones. I link my symptoms to the fact that I had mentally abusive parents who judged and screamed at me for every little thing. My brain constantly trying to seek perfection seems to me to be a coping method to avoid further fear.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to understand that Thoughts, Emotions and Behaviours are interconnected, meaning: If you change one of it, the other will usually follow.

Secondly, I would like to introduce to you to the ABC, where A stands for Adversity (either internally or externally),  B stands for Beliefs, and C stands for Consequences (which are thinking, behaving and feeling consequences that are spawned from these underlying beliefs). Most people jump from A -> C and neglect their beliefs.

Without going too deep, if you have a belief about uncomfort you have to tell yourself that it's hard to tolerate, but you can tolerate it and it's in your best interest to do so.

It's always about tolerating discomfort as well as thinking and behaving in a helpful way.

If you want to reduce fear or uncomfort, one needs to rehearse helpful thoughts before, in the midst and after the adversity and act according to these thoughts. This ensures that you are in a rational  frame of mind. This can be called uncomfort by acting

On the other hand, uncomfort by abstaining is a little bit different, but you still have to tolerate discomfort since you want to abstain from something because  -again-it is in your best interest to do so.

Usually, OCD patients are provided with behavioral and acceptance methods. Debating with thoughts in a long-winded fashion will just re-activate unhelpful beliefs, and that's precisely the reason why once you have reharsed your helpful thoughts you should then switch to an **acceptance based focus**, where you **don't try to get rid or engage in your thoughts**. Behavioral methods can be precisely like mentioned above (uncomfort by abstaining if you ruminate a lot, for example, you ask yourself the question: Does my rumination really change anything? I'm here in my room right now and ruminating won't change a thing. If you rehearse such thinking and behave in line with these thoughts, with time your beliefs will change.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you trained (meditation) under a competent teacher.
If you do it your own make sure you have a full understanding of meditation methods. In that case, start your practice slowly.
Seek professional help if you think that you are not well.

Is meditation bad for you?

https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=33016&p=491012&hilit=